# Can I use calc-eval to solve an equation?

Tags: calc

I regularly use `calc-eval` in the `*scratch*` buffer to work out some quick calculations. I know that I can use some simple functions inside the calculation string, e.g. log. However I am not certain whether I can use the solver in the same way.

Is it possible to write a `calc-eval` expression that solves for, say, a particular variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
(calc-eval "solve([x+y=3, x-y=1], [x,y])")
```

evaluates to:

```
"[x = 2, y = 1]"
```

You might find it more comfortable to use a `calc-mode` buffer than running `calc-eval` in the scratch buffer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out section 11.6 of the Calc manual, which is about solving equations. I just use `calc-mode` rather than calling `calc-eval` by hand, but it seems like you'd be able to use the functions it describes.